# Why doesn't map insert?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, iterator

Why doesn't UpdateLapMap insert a UapMap when the lap is not found?

```
typedef std::map<int, int> UapMap; // map of uap counters
typedef std::map<int, UapMap> LapMap; // map of UapMaps
LapMap m_LapMap;

void MyClass::UpdateLapMap( int lap, int * uaps, size_t n_uaps )
{
   std::map<int, UapMap>::iterator itLap = m_LapMap.find( lap );
   if ( itLap == m_LapMap.end( ) )
   {
      printf( "not found - insert new lap %d\n", lap );
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_uaps; i++ ) itLap->second[ uaps[ i ] ] = 1; // initial count
   }
   else
   {
      /// insert and/or increment uap counters
   }
}
```

Comment: Modifying what is equivalent to `m_LapMap.end( )` looks weird.

Comment: The end iterator is one past the last object.  When `itLap == m_LapMap.end( )` does `itLap` point to a valid object?

Comment: Take a break to think over what you want to achieve, this isn't it.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: A yes. I see why it is not working. Trying to insert a new UapMap into the LapMap. Need to create the UapMap, then insert it, and not at map.end

Comment: @MikeCAT If you copy your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `itLap->second` when `itLap == m_LapMap.end( )`.

[`std::map::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end) returns a placeholder element and attempting to access it invokes *undefined behavior*.

`UpdateLapMap` doesn't insert a `UapMap` because there are no code to insert a `UapMap`, so you should add that.

for example:

```
   if ( itLap == m_LapMap.end( ) )
   {
      printf( "not found - insert new lap %d\n", lap );
      itLap = m_LapMap.insert( LapMap::value_type( lap, UapMap() ) ).first; // add this line
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_uaps; i++ ) itLap->second[ uaps[ i ] ] = 1; // initial count
   }
```

[`std::map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) used here returns a pair of an iterator pointing at the inserted element and a boolean value indicating whether insertion is done or the key has already existed, so the iterator is taken via `.first`.